# How use nested div and checkboxes after selecting parent radio in jsp

Tags: spring, checkbox, radio-button, jstl, jsp-tags

I have 2 radio buttons which represents USA and CANADA. If I select USA radio button I wanted a div tag to display Address1, Address2, County, State, Email,and 2 check boxes one will give option to opt for E-mail news letter and other is to opt for Twitter updates.

And If I select CANADA radio button I wanted a div tag with Address 1, State and Email and one check box for e-mail news letter. Note: Here I dont want address 2, county text boxes and Twitter checkbox.

Once User fills required information; I wanted to capture all those values including selected country radio value into myRegistrationForm.address (Address is a complex object with address1,address 2, county, state, email and country String properties and emailNewsLetter, twitterUpdates boolean properties) using spring:bind.

Here is the sample snippet I am trying to achieve. Thanks in advance for helping me out.

```
<td>
<spring:bind path="registerForm.address">
<input type="radio" name="country" value="USA" <c:if test='${status.value == "USA"}'>checked</c:if>> USA
<!-- If above radio is selected I need  dynamic div table with some textboxes and 2 check boxes and needs to be captured -->
<c:if test='${status.value == "USA"}'>
    <div id="address-usa">
        Address 1: <input type="text" name="addressOne"/>
        Address 2: <input type="text" name="addressTwo"/>
        County: <input type="text" name="county"/>
        State: <input type="text" name="state"/>
        Email: <input type="email" name="email"/>
        <input type="checkbox" value="NEWSLETTER">E-Mail News Letter
        <input type="checkbox" value="twitter">Twitter Updates
    </div>
</c:if> 

<input type="radio" name="country" value="CANADA" <c:if test='${status.value == "CANADA"}'>checked</c:if>> CANADA
<c:if test='${status.value == "CANADA"}'>
    <div id="address-canada">
        Address 1: <input type="text" name="addressOne"/>
        <!-- Note I dont need address 2 and county for canada -->
        State: <input type="text" name="state"/>
        Email: <input type="email" name="email"/>
        <input type="checkbox" value="NEWSLETTER">E-Mail News Letter
        <!-- No twitter updates for canada customers -->
    </div>
</c:if> 
</spring:bind>
</td>
```

To be more precise: I wanted to bellow html/jsp code wrapped with `<spring:nestedPath/> <spring:bind> <c:foreach> <c:if>`

You can run the following code using  http://jsfiddle.net/eKFrW/298/

```
<label><input id="rdb1" type="radio" name="toggler" value="1" />USA</label>
<label><input id="rdb2" type="radio" name="toggler" value="2" />CANADA</label>

<div id="blk-1" class="toHide" style="display:none">
    Address 1: <input type="text" name="addressOne"><br/>
    Address 2: <input type="text" name="addressTwo"><br/>
    County : <input type="text" name="county"><br/>
    Email : <input type="email" name="email"><br/>
    E-mail News Letter: <input type="checkbox" name="emailLetter">
    Twitter Updates : <input type="checkbox" name="twitterUpdates">
</div>
<div id="blk-2" class="toHide" style="display:none">
    Address 1: <input type="text" name="addressOne"><br/>
    Email : <input type="email" name="email"><br/>
    E-mail News Letter: <input type="checkbox" name="emailLetter">
</div>​
```

And associated Java Script:

```
$(function() {
    $("[name=toggler]").click(function(){
            $('.toHide').hide();
            $("#blk-"+$(this).val()).show('slow');
    });
 });​
```

Comment: Can anybody help. I need this as soon as possible.